# trying to create an adaptor file for qt application via xml

Tags: xml, qt, c++11, dbus, qtwebengine

- below is the xml code for creating adaptor

  > Introspection 1.0//EN"
  >   "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
  >
  > ```
  >    <node>   <interface name="conn.brw.IHistoryManager">
  >
  >    <method name="deleteAllItems">
  >        <arg name="retval" type="(i)" direction="out"/>
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.Out0" value="conn::brw::ERROR_IDS" />
  >    </method>
  >
  >    <method name="deleteItem">
  >        <arg name="a_i32Uid" type="i" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="retval" type="i" direction="out"/>
  >         <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In0" value="const conn::brw::HistoryItemList &amp;" />
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.Out0" value="conn::brw::ERROR_IDS" />
  >    </method>
  >
  >    <method name="deleteItemsInRange">
  >        <arg name="a_i64BeginTime" type="(x)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="a_i64EndTime" type="(x)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="retval" type="(i)" direction="out"/>
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In0" value="const conn::brw::HistoryItemList &amp;" />
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In1" value="const conn::brw::HistoryItemList &amp;" />
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.Out0" value="conn::brw::ERROR_IDS" />
  >    </method>
  >
  >    <method name="getItems">
  >        <arg name="a_i64BeginVisitTime" type="(x)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="a_i64EndVisitTime" type="(x)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="a_esortType" type="(i)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="a_u32StartIndex" type="(u)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="a_u32ItemsCount" type="(u)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="a_oItem" type="a(ixxiuu)" direction="out"/>
  >        <arg name="retval" type="(i)" direction="out"/>
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In2" value="conn::brw::BOOKMARK_SORT_TYPE" />
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.Out0" value="conn::brw::ERROR_IDS" />
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.Out1" value="conn::brw::HistoryItemList &amp;" />
  >    </method>
  >
  >        <method name="getItemsCount">
  >        <arg name="a_i64BeginVisitTime" type="(x)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="a_i64EndVisitTIme" type="(x)" direction="in"/>
  >        <arg name="retval" type="(u)" direction="out"/>
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In0" value="const conn::brw::HistoryItemList &amp;" />
  >        <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In1" value="const conn::brw::HistoryItemList &amp;" />
  >
  >    </method>
  >        <method name="getMaxHistoryNumber">
  >        <arg name="retval" type="(u)" direction="out"/>
  >
  >    </method>
  >    <signal name="onChanged">
  >    <arg name="retval" type="i" direction="out"/>
  >    <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.out0" value="const conn::brw::ERROR_IDS" />
  >    </signal>
  >
  >
  >
  >  </interface> </node>
  > ```

  while building it is giving the following error.

  :-1: error: [ihistorymanager_adaptor.h] Error 1

please help. thanks

Comment: It's not the whole file. It should start with `<node>` and `<interface>`.

Comment: i just missed that part, now it is fine, i think.